# MySQL: Como obtengo el valor maximo de un grupo y valor minimo de otro grupo

Tags: mysql

Alguien podría ayudar a resolver mi siguiente problema, tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
- Value - | --------- Date -------- | ---- GPS --- | -- Status -
----------+-------------------------+--------------+--------------
    120   |   2020-06-21 01:10:06   |    3212456   |      0
     56   |   2020-06-21 02:20:06   |    3212456   |      1
     45   |   2020-06-21 05:35:06   |    3212456   |      1
     23   |   2020-06-21 08:40:06   |    3212456   |      1
    150   |   2020-06-21 10:55:06   |    3212456   |      0
    190   |   2020-06-21 12:58:06   |    3212456   |      0
```

Desde una sola consulta MySql, necesito obtener el valor Máximo o Mínimo del campo `Value`, con las siguientes condiciones.

Existen 2 grupos para el campo `Status`, grupos `'0'` y grupos `'1'`.

**CASO 1:** Si la cantidad de registros del grupo '1' es mayor o igual al los registros del grupo '0'
Desde la consulta debo obtener solo el valor máximo del campo `Value` correspondiente al grupo '1'.

**CASO 2:** Si solo existen registros para el grupo '0' (Es decir, no existen registros para el grupo '1'), desde la consulta debo obtener solo el valor mínimo del campo `Value` correspondiente al grupo '0'.

NOTAS:
El caso 1 tiene prioridad sobre el caso 2, esto quiere decir que solo debe ejecutarse un solo caso.
En la tabla siempre existirá por lo menos 1 registro del grupo '0', no así para el grupo '1'.

Desde ya le agradezco cualquier ayuda.....
Saludos !

Comment: Saludos. Le falto incluir el SQL que realizaste para tal fin; así mismo acompañarlo del error o resultado erroneo que está obteniendo; así se le indica que hacer.

Comment: Para el caso 1, el resultado debe ser:  Value = 56

, Para el caso 2, el resultado debe ser:  Value =  120

Comment: SELECT status, MAX(value), MIN(value)
FROM tabla
GROUP BY status

Comment: La consulta que utilizo me entrega los valores max y min a la vez. Solo necesito un resultado segun las condiciones que comente anteriormente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Necesitas resolverlo con una subconsulta, que en primer lugar te retorne:

- Cantidad de `Status = 0`
- Cantidad de `Status = 1`
- Valor máximo de `Value` para `Status = 1`
- Valor mínimo de `Value` para `Status = 0`

Con estos cuatro valores puedes solucionar las dos condiciones que planteas:

```
select case when T.Count1 >= T.CountO then MaxValue1
            when T.Count1 = 0 and T.CountO > 0 then MinValue0
       end
       from ( select count(case when Status = 0 then 1 else NULL end)   as Count0,
                     count(case when Status = 1 then 1 else NULL end)   as Count1,
                     max(case when Status = 1 then Value else NULL end) as MaxValue1,
                     min(case when Status = 0 then Value else NULL end) as MinValue0
                     from TuTabla
       ) AS T
```

Usamos funciones de agregación condicionales, `count`, `max`, `min` pero condicionadas mediante un `case when .. end`

Comment: Gracias Patricio por tu ayuda, pero me aparece el siguiente error: Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Si, es exactamente lo que dice el error, hay que agregar un alias de tabla a la subconsulta, revisa mi edición.

Comment: A tu primera edición le agregue al final ' AS T ' y también funciono correcto. Cual de las dos ediciones recomiendas como optima.

Comment: Usar el `AS` es siempre más explicito, por lo cual es mejor

Comment: Patricio, te agradezco enormemente tu ayuda porque pude resolver mi problema. Gracias ...

Comment: Patricio, si a la misma consulta ademas quiero agregarle un filtro por hora, es decir, que me filtre los datos de la ultima hora, sería optima esta forma:

Comment: where Date between
DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB('2020-06-21 03:00:00', interval 1 hour), "%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00") and
DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB('2020-06-21 03:00:00', interval 1 hour), "%Y-%m-%d %H:59:59")

Comment: O existe un forma mas corta de hacerlo.

Comment: Si es de la última hora podrías hacer algo así: `WHERE DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR) > Date`

Comment: No funciona porque no filtra, muestra todos los registros.

Comment: Perdón, es así: `WHERE Date > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -2 HOUR) `

Comment: Tampoco funciona correctamente, también probé esto y los resultados no son correctos: where Date >= DATE_SUB('2020-06-21 03:00:00',INTERVAL 1 HOUR)

Comment: Para poder analizar el problema aisle la consulta, solo con esto: SELECT * FROM MiTabla
where Date >= DATE_SUB('2020-06-21 03:00:00',INTERVAL 1 HOUR)

Comment: Hola Patricio, puedes ayudarme a traducir este mismo código SQL a LINQ para utilizarlo en Entity Frameworl 5.0. Lo he intentado, pero esta complejo.

Comment: Lamentablemente tengo muy poca experiencia con LINQ, pero por que no pones una pregunta nueva al respecto?

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta.